# p argument in trainControl

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

In the caret [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/trainControl), the p argument of trainControl refers to "For leave-group out cross-validation: the training percentage".

Could anyone please explain the difference of the following when defining a 10-fold cross validation for passing to the train function of the caret package -

(a). control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, p=.9)

(b). control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)

As an example, say if we have a data set of 10,000 observations.  As we have 10 folds for both, for (a), my understanding is that each fold would have 1,000 of the observations and each time nine folds with a total of 9000 observations (90%) would be used for training. For (b), 9 folds for training would together have 750 (75%) of the observations (as the default value of p=.75) with the remaining fold for testing always having 250 (25%) observations.  Is my understanding correct ?

Do you call both 10-fold cross validation ? Or should the first one be called leave-group out 10-fold cross-validation ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. When quoting from somewhere (including documentation), it is good practice to also include the relevant link. Kindly edit & update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.  I have added the link to the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

When using

`control <- trainControl(method = "LGOCV", number = 10, p=.9)`

you will perform 10 repetitions of leave group validation where for each repetition 90% (p = 0.9) of the data will be sampled at random and used for training while the remaining 10% of data will be used for testing. This is also called Monte-Carlo Cross Validation. Usually more repetitions are performed with MC-CV.

When using

`control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)`

the data set will be split into 10 parts and 10 resampling iterations will be performed. In each iteration 9 parts will be used for training and the remaining part will be used for testing. This will progress until all the parts are used once for testing. This is called K-fold cross validation. In this case K is 10.

Further reading: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51416/k-fold-vs-monte-carlo-cross-validation

In each case around 90% of the data will be used for training in each resampling iteration.

**EDIT**: I have changed the above code

`control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, p=.9)`

to

`control <- trainControl(method = "LGOCV", number = 10, p=.9)`

since if you specify `cv` you will actually preform k-fold CV and the p argument will be ignored. So in order to perform leave group out cross validation you must specify `method = "LGOCV"` and then the `p` argument will be used to determine the train/test split ratio.

Comment: Many thanks for the clear explanation.  I guess I was confused by the default p value of 0.75.  Does it mean that the p value will be ignored if not specified ?

Comment: like in any R function, if an argument has a default value (p = 0.75), it will be used if the argument is not specified. However I made a mistake, you can not specify `cv` in train control and expect `LGOCV` check my edit

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  It seems to me that even some experts can get this mixed up.  There are definitely textbooks around that equate trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, p=.9) to 10-fold cross validation.  Much appreciated.

Comment: `trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, p=.9)` is 10-fold CV and `p =.9` is totally redundant in that code

Comment: Thanks for the tip but in any case, when specifying the `p` argument, I always end up with `p = 0.75` in the output. I really don't understand why.

Comment: @FrsLry could you post a question with a reproducible example? I am not sure I follow you.